# Postfix not starting in gitlab docker container

Tags: postfix, docker, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab

I am trying to get postfix running on the gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.3.6-ce.0 docker container and it doesn't seem to work startup

I get the following error:

```
postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed
```

My config looks like:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, ipayroll.co.nz, ip-10-136-28-218.ap- 
southeast-2.compute.internal, localhost.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal, localhost
myhostname = ip-10-136-28-218.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated 
defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = 
btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

and here is the os of the image:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

I believe this is an issue with the container as I have got postfix going before, on other containers. I just can't figure it out on this one. I have tried many methods of installing postfix but this is the general one I use.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install postfix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was I was running my commands using the wrong shell, I was using /bin/bash and not /bin/sh. Once I tried doing this through the dockerfile and starting via an entrypoint all went well.